# Why does motherboard manual recommend single-channel configuration with two DIMMs?

Tags: memory, motherboard

Why is ASUS recommending the middle configuration with 2 DIMMs as opposed to installing one stick in each channel for dual-channel operation? This is a server-grade motherboard, specifically the WS C246M PRO.

[image: Excerpt from ASUS manual]

Comment: Smash that downvote button! Can we get 1000 downvotes?!?

Comment: If the manual doesn't explain why, then we're left to guess why the manufacturer wrote it that way. But this site expects answers to answer the question definitely, not with guesses, so this isn't a good question for this site. My recommendation is to ignore their recommendation and use your best judgement when choosing which slots to use.

Comment: Of course. Answers can only be black and white. A non-absolute answer is a non-answer. Terminating program.

Comment: I would contact Asus support, only they have an absolute answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Page 1-6 of the [manual](https://dlcdnets.asus.com/pub/ASUS/mb/socket1151/WS-C246M-PRO/Manual/E14689_WS_C246M_PRO_UM_V2_WEB_u.pdf) states "The system maps the total size of the lower-sized channel for the dual-channel configuration. Any excess memory from the higher-sized channel is then mapped for single-channel operation." That indicates the memory controller manages everything.

Also, page 117 shows the block diagram which confirms using 1A and 1B populate one DDR channel each per DIMM. [image: Memory-CPU section of block diagram]

Comment: Great find with that block diagram. So it looks like their recommended configuration is dual channel after all. Confusing because it goes against convention, but there you go,  A1 and A2 are on separate channels.